# Set up "bluetooth hc-06" on pcb

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, drawing

My teacher gave me a task to design a circuit board in P-CAD 2006. There is HC-06 Bluetooth module on the board. Unfortunately it has no usual smd or dip pins. Instead it looks like this (red arrow):

[image]

My teacher told me that It should be designed in powerful cad system like Mentors Graphics or similar. P-CAD 2006 doesn't provide such kind of pins and I have to design this pins like rounded rectangle smd.

I made this in P-CAD but now I have to make a 2D drawing in AutoCad of setting this module on the board. It should look something like this:

[image]

The main problem that I cannot find the image or drawing of this in Internet and I cannot find the technology of making this. What soldering or gaskets should I use? I really must do this drawing in AutoCad. Can you help me with this? Maybe you have some pictures that I can make a drawing from it?
I appreciate any kind of help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The board is *castellated*, with a cut-away through-hole pattern on the edges.  Such items are typically mounted onto SMD (surface mount device) pads on PCBs.  If you search for the datasheet of your module, you'll get some precise math for the pattern of castellations that you could design a SMD footprint for in a CAD package.  There are dxl and eagle footprints available [HERE](http://store.iteadstudio.com/index.php?main_page=product_info&products_id=157), with no assertions on my part as to whether they're correct or not. You should be able to import the DXL into many different CAD packages.

You don't mention your background or environment, but your question seems to indicate you're in over your head.  I suggest working closely with your teacher.

Answer (score 1):

The pads to receive the module on the board can be simple rectangles, nothing fancy (photo from [Sparkfun](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/assets/learn_tutorials/3/6/2/How_to_solder_castallated_via_tutorial-20.jpg)).

[image]

You can find a datasheet from ***Guangzhou HC Information Technology Co., Ltd.***  with detailed dimensions for the HC06 BT module [here](https://www.olimex.com/Products/Components/RF/BLUETOOTH-SERIAL-HC-06/resources/hc06.pdf)

[image]